# Duckduckgo API not displaying results

Tags: php, api

Im using the duckduckgo API with PHP. The API works but if I search for a phrase nothing appears in my browser. If I search for 'Freelance', search results appear. However if I type something more specific nothing appears. Is there something that I can do to allow phrase results to appear?  Here is my code

```
<?php

require_once("DuckDuckGoZeroclickInfo.php");
$obj = new DuckDuckGoZeroclickInfo("", "");
$response = $obj-> zeroClickInfo("Freelance", $callback = null, $no_html = null, $no_redirect = null, $skip_disambig = null);
print "Raw Body: $response->rawBody"; 
var_dump($response->body); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing spaces with a + in your search string?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply write your own API calls instead of using Mashape PHP libary that has not been updated for some time.

Their API uri's are formed like so:

```
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json&pretty=1
```

or in your case: `http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=freelance&format=json`

Main url for query `http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=` followed by your query string where spaces are replaced by `+` followed by `&format=json` or `&format=xml`

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a go but again I dont get results for some query's. For example I didnt get any results for this...http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=the%20order+processing+database&format=json

Comment: @user1781162 the reason you're not seeing results for certain queries is because this is our Instant Answer API. It only provides Instant Answer results for queries, when available. It does not provide the link results that you see on https//:duckduckgo.com. We do not have syndication rights for those links and so we can't make them available through any other means.